# OS X Autolayout - Arranging views around main view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to arrange eight views around one main central view so that as the main view is programatically moved or resized, the surrounding views keep their same positions. This link shows the layout.

[http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bernie.w/Autolayout.png http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bernie.w/Autolayout.png](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bernie.w/Autolayout.png).

Note:

1. Views 2 & 7 are vertically centred on the main view.
2. Views 4 & 5 are horizontally centred on the main view.

I'm new to autolayout, so any pointers how to achieve the above appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add horizontal spacing constraints between 4 and Main view then 5 and Main view.  Then add vertical spacing constraints between 7 and Main view then 2 and Main view.  You should then be able to do vertical spacing 'greater than or equal to' from 1 to 4 then do horizontal spacing 'greater than or equal to' from 1 to 2.  Repeat that 'greater than or equal to' process for horizontal spacing and vertical spacing for the 1-3-5, 5-8-7, and 4-6-7 views and you should get the result that you want.  Let me know if you have any questions about that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply MSU_Bulldog.

Comment: Think I need some help with this. My test project is here: [link](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bernie.w/AutoLayout.zip). When you say "add horizontal spacing constraints between 4 and Main view, do I select both views then choose Editor/Pin/Horizontal Spacing?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how to add the horizontal spacing.  Do the same for vertical spacing.  If you click on 4, for example, then click the ruler in the Utilities bar on the right side of the screen, you can find the horizontal and vertical constraints that you have set.  For 1,3,6, and 8, change these from = to >= to have a 'greater than or equals' setting.  That is so that they can resize to be bigger than what you have set.

Comment: Thanks MSU_Bulldog. Well, I couldn’t get it to work with 'my understanding' of your settings, but this seems to do the trick:

1. Views 1, 3, 6 & 8 horizontally and vertically pinned to main view.
2. Views 4 & 5 horizontally pinned and centre Y aligned to main view.
3. Views 2 & 7 vertically pinned and centre X aligned to main view.

If you can see any drawbacks with the above, please let me know.

Now, on programmatically changing the main view frame, the outer views remain where they are. I wonder if this is a limitation of autolayout?